# Database design, reducing join

Tags: sql, database, database-design

This is a db for online store for tickets (such as Airbnb experience)

For a product (ticket),

there are available days (and times)

On an available day,
 - there could be multiple options (such as beginner-class, advanced-class)
 - there is a quantity that can be sold (shared among multiple options)

One way to represent this is

```
Product
  name

Variant (Option)
  product

TimeSlot
  product
  date
  time
  quantity


TimeslotVariant
  variant
  timeslot
```

Another way would be the following.

I see two main differences,

- First difference

  - Above: you need join on `TimeSlot` to find what variants are on given day.
  - Below: you can directly query `TimeVariant`
- Second difference

  - Above: `[{date, time, [variant1, variant2], quantity}]` (I think client application would prefer this)
  - Below: `[{date, time, variant1}, {date, time, variant2}]` + `[{date, time, quantity}]`

---

```
Product
  name

Variant (Option)
  product


TimeSlot
  product
  date
  time
  quantity

TimeVariant
  variant
  date
  time
```

I think the first option is more intuitive (?) but I also think additional join can be painful to maintain sometimes

What questions (criteria) should I ask to myself to decide among the two?

Comment: Will a timeslot variant ALWAYS (emphasis in always, forever and ever, even when requirements change...) coincide with a time slot? If yes, then the first option is better; If no, definitively the second one is more flexible.

Comment: I'm having hard time imagining future requirements where second one would be better, (not that there would be none, just I'm new to the question itself) Can you give me one?

Comment: "intuitive" is objective. Referential integrity is not. It comes down to the question imposed by @TheImpaler. Also, there's nothing wrong with joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, The number of joins is probably not the most important question you need to ask yourself when designing a relational database.

the most important question is how can you make sure you protect the data integrity.
The data integrity is best kept with the first option you've presented, so this is the option you should go with.

If the joins is what's bothering you, you can always use views to "flatten" the data.

But why the first option is better?
Because the primary key (or, at least the natural key) of the `TimeSlot` table must be comprised of `product`, `date` and  `time` - and the second option doesn't take the product into consideration in the `TimeVariant` table.

You could add the `product` to that table as well, and some DBAs would suggest that as the best option (those would be the DBAs that are opposing to using surrogate keys) - but personally, even though I'm not a DBA myself I think that a surrogate key have it's advantages and one of them is exactly what you have here - you can use a single column instead of three to join two tables - which makes your life much easier (and with enforcing uniqueness of the natural key(s) of the table there's no integrity problem with surrogate keys).

Comment: Can you elaborate on `you can use a single column to join two tables instead of three `
single column would be TimeSlot's surrogate key, and what are `two` and ` three` tables?

Comment: I meant using one column instead of three columns to join both tables. Is that less confusing now? (I'll edit that into my answer if it is)

Answer (score 0):

First you should think do you want to reduce joining overheads ? If yes then you may use flatten data stored in the views.

First Case

In the **TimeslotVariant**  you have added **variant** and **timeslot**  through which only by querying the TimeslotVariant table you will get your intended data. In this case your data integrity in okay.

Second Case

If you add product key to your TimeslotVariant then only to show the product listing will serve the purpose though time and date are also getting re-entry.

My suggestion is to keep the first case and store the flatten data in a view.